# Get TeamCity to notify the user and commit that produced a failed build

Tags: jsp, teamcity, freemarker

I am managing [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for a project and I can´t get a hold of [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/) (the language it uses for the email templates). Could anyone help me access the last commit into the template?

Right now it looks like this (code following the text):

> Build Project :: Develop #0.3.0.330 (dev) failed (Tests failed: 1 (1 new), passed: 1688)
>   Agent: Server-5
>
> Changes included: 28 changes, only 20 are shown.
>   Change aa554cff00cc77ef85ad215a4bc39ef3f4b6d1b9 by masterofpuppis (3 files): corrección registro screen
>   Change f2346f28b800e11b2f9989c8813957a14f76f633 by masterofpuppis (1 file): método create file en el init de loginscrreenmodel

```
<#macro build_changes bean>
  <#-- @ftlvariable name="bean" type="jetbrains.buildServer.notification.impl.ChangesBean" -->
  <#-- @ftlvariable name="webLinks" type="jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.WebLinks" -->
  <div>
    <#assign modNum=bean.modificationsNumber/>
    <#if (modNum > 0)>
      <div style="${separatorStyle}"></div>
      <br/>
      <div>
        <#assign changesLink><a href='${webLinks.getViewChangesUrl(bean.build)}'>${modNum} change<@plural modNum/></a></#assign>
        Changes included: ${changesLink}<#if bean.changesClipped>,
        only ${bean.modifications?size} are shown</#if>.
      </div>
      <#list bean.modifications as mod>
        <#assign pers><#if mod.personal>(personal build)</#if></#assign>
        <#assign description=mod.description?html/>
        <#if description?length == 0><#assign description='&lt;no comment&gt;'/></#if>
        <div>
          <#assign modLink><a href='${webLinks.getChangeFilesUrl(mod.id, mod.personal)}'>${mod.changes?size} file<@plural mod.changes?size/></a></#assign>
          Change ${mod.displayVersion} ${pers} by ${mod.userName} (${modLink}):
          <i>${description?replace("(\r?\n|\r)", "<br>", "r")?trim}</i>
        </div>
      </#list>
    </#if>
  </div>
</#macro>
```

What I would like to see is something like:

> Build Project :: Develop #0.3.0.330 (dev) failed (Tests failed: 1 (1 new), passed: 1688)
>   Agent: Server-5. User: masterofpuppis. Last commit: correción registro

Seems like this should be rather easy but I am not seeing it. I thank you in advance for whatever guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

This code should display what you wanted.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code in the **answer itself**, not in an image.